# remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isspace); what does the ::isspace means?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm recently want to find a way to trim string by using STL. I saw somebody use

```
remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isspace);
```

I found `isspace` is a funtion in stl, the header is `<ctype.h>`. I put the above code and header file in my function, then it could not pass the compile. The compiler is complaining something about `isspace`.

I try

```
remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::isspace);
```

it still could not pass the compilation.

Then I found another guys use

```
remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isspace);
```

I try this, it could pass the compilation.

My question is that

1. why I could not pass the compilation by using the first two ways.
2. what does the `::isspace` means? Is it want to mention it belongs to the STL or anything else? I am confused about the usage of `::`?

Comment: I am pretty sure ::isspace is a correct usage, because I saw some guys use this way to solve leetcode problems

Comment: `::whatever` means look up whatever starting from the global namespace (vs the current namespace).

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity If so, I found isspace is belongs to std, why I use std::isspace could not pass the compilation?

Comment: Unfortunately, using `::isspace` formally requires that you include the deprecated C `<ctype.h>` header. Passing a signed character with a negative value other than EOF will cause undefined behaviour, too.

Comment: Include `<cctype>` and `std::isspace` should work. C header files (the ones ending in `.h`) don't know about `std` so that's why it didn't work.

Comment: @zenith, Except there's an overload taking a locale in another header, so in general, you can't rely on that working alone. What you *can* do is wrap it in a proper lambda that also removes potential undefined behaviour: `[](unsigned char c) {return std::isspace(c);}`

Comment: @zenith I tried as you mentioned add <cctype> and std::isspace, it doesn't work for me.  But still thank you.

Comment: The correct way to pass a `char` to `isspace` etc. is to first convert it to `unsigned char` and then to `int`, i.e., what @chris does. Don't directly pass pointers to these classification functions to`remove_if` (or other standard algorithms) with iterators into a `std::string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::isspace` is an overloaded function in C++, with a template function declared in `<locale>`. Implementations are allowed to silently include additional headers you didn't ask for, and many do so. They do so because they internally make use of those additional headers.

Normally, the argument passed to `std::isspace` would determine which overload gets picked, but in your case, you're not passing any argument, you're attempting to merely determine its address.

`::isspace` works, because that isn't an overloaded function.

It's like

```
template <typename T>
void f(T) { }

void g(int) { }
void h() { f(g); } // okay, g is not an overloaded function

void i(int) { }
void i(char) { }
void j() { f(i); } // error, the compiler cannot know whether you want the void(int)
                   // function, or the void(char) one
```

What you have been told in the comments is right, the simple way of making sure it works is by not passing the address of `isspace` at all, but creating a function of your own that calls `isspace`. You need to do so anyway for other reasons, but it also nicely avoids the problem entirely.

Comment: One more question. Do I need to overload this function? Because I just want to remove space and \0 in one string. Why I could not use ::isspace directly?

Comment: @Teddy It would compile if you use `::isspace` directly, but as pointed out in the comments on your question, the argument `::isspace` expects to get does not match the argument that `remove_if` will pass to it.

Answer (score 3):

`::isspace` means you're explicitly calling the global method `isspace`.  The C Standard Library methods are all globals, and `<ctype.h>` is a C Standard Library header.

Namespaces don't exist in C, so when using the C library headers, you don't use the std namespace.  The C++ counterpart to `<ctype.h>` which uses the std namespace is `<cctype>`.

The leading `::` notation is useful when you're trying to deal with name conflicts.  For example, you could have code like this...

```
void DoSomething(void);

class Foo {
  void DoSomething (void); // Uhoh, this method shadows the global DoSomething.
  void DoSomethingElse(void) {
    Foo::DoSomething(); // Calls the class local DoSomething()
    ::DoSomething(); // Calls the global DoSomething()
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that in C++ there are two my knowledge two versions of the `std::ispace` function, i.e. two overloads. The first of these is defined in the `<cctype>` C-compatibility header as

```
#include <ctype.h>
namespace std { using isspace = ::isspace; }
```

Where `<ctype.h>` is the respective C header which should define `isspace` (in the global namespace, i.e. `::isspace`) as:

```
int isspace(int);
```

The second overload is defined in `<locale>` as:

```
namespace std {
  template<class charT> bool isspace(charT, const locale &);
}
```

If for some reason you include (directly or indirectly) both `<cctype>` and `<locale>`, you get two overrides for `std::isspace` but one global `::isspace` function. Hence, using `::isspace` directly will work well, but using `std::isspace` will error, because of the compiler is unable to resolve the ambiguity of which overload to use.

To work around this you can tell the compiler which overload you meant by casting the function to the required type, for example:

```
std::remove_if(str.begin(),
               str.end(),
               static_cast<int(&)(int)>(std::isspace)); // reference to function
    // Or even static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::isspace)); // pointer to function
```

PS: The literal `::` is called the scope resolution operator, so in case of `A::b` it refers to something called `b` in the reachable namespace `A` in the current context. When `::` is not preceded by a name, it refers to the global namespace. See [[expr.prim.id.qual]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.qual) in the latest C++ standard draft for details.